# "Exec format error" running a binary created by g++

Tags: linux, bash, makefile

I have a problem with my QTCreator-generated Makefile. Everything is working fine except when I try to create myself a new executable file for my tests, my terminal says: `bash: ./RunTests: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error`

**Here is how my MakeFile rule looks like:**

```
TESTS: ../WannaBeRPG/testes.cpp ../WannaBeRPG/hero.h ../WannaBeRPG/charinterface.h
    $(CXX) -c $(CXXFLAGS) $(INCPATH) -o RunTests ../WannaBeRPG/testes.cpp
```

**Flags are:**

```
CXX = g++
CXXFLAGS = -pipe -g -std=gnu++0x -Wall -W -fPIC $(DEFINES)
INCPATH = -I../WannaBeRPG -I. -I/usr/lib64/qt5/mkspecs/linux-g++
DEFINES = -DQT_QML_DEBUG
```

If that is anyhow helpful here is my testes.cpp file:

```
#include <gtest/gtest.h>
#include "hero.h"

TEST(teee, HPTEST)
{
    Hero myHero("Hika",150,100,0,0,0,0,0,0,0);
    EXPECT_EQ(100,myHero.getHP());
}

int main_tests(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    testing::InitGoogleTest(&argc,argv);
    return RUN_ALL_TESTS();
}
```

I am using Fedora.
Any ideas why does this works this way? Primary exec from this Makefile works completely fine.

Comment: I am not 100% sure why this is happening in your case, but for ./RunTests to execute it must have execute permission and the directory in which it is contained must have execute permission: $ls -l RunTests should return something like -rwxr-xr-x or at least -rwx------ or at least -r-x------. Also check the directory in which it is found: it also must have the "x" for execute permission. You might have a problem with the value of your "umask" variable. That is, when a new file is created, execute permission is stripped from it. Read up on umask.

Comment: @ThomasHedden, a permission problem wouldn't cause "Exec format error".

Comment: As an aside, one of the steps to take when dealing with this kind of problem is to use `file RunTests` to determine the type of the binary.

Comment: Yeah, that it not a matter even if I change premissions to 777 it is still the same error.

@CharlesDuffy 'file RunTest ' prints me: 'RunTests: ELF 64-bit LSB relocatable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), not stripped'

Comment: ...now, compare that `file` output to what you have for your working linked executable. You'll see that that one says `executable`, not `relocatable`.

Comment: Aside: Don't use `777` even temporarily to test with. Assigning `o+w` permissions, which that includes, means that any other user on the system that can navigate to your directory can modify your binary, injecting malicious code. "Any other user" includes accounts like `nobody`, which is often used to sandbox authentication code handling untrusted input from as-yet-unauthenticated users to remote services.

Comment: Do you realize you just wrote testes? That kind of means something especially different than tests. Careful misspelling if you are doing this for a class or even work...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `-c` argument to `g++` tells it not to link your binary. Thus, your output file is an object file rather than an executable.

Comment: Ok, but when I remove the -c flag the whole make process crashes giving my a lot of undefined references, i.e. one to 'undefined ref. to main' which cannot be defined second time while it is already being in the main.cpp file of the whole project.

Comment: If your test executable doesn't have a `main` function, how do you expect it to run?

Comment: I get the point. Why does it crashes with all of these undef. refs though ( I mean if I add a main function to compile it)? Shall I link them somewhere separately or what?

Comment: Any libraries that need to be linked in to you the functions your program uses are, well, libraries that need to be linked in to get you the functions your program uses. Address it the same way you do when linking your main executable if the list of dependencies is the same.

Comment: BANG! THAT WAS IT! Thanks you a lot! :)